# Custom SCDF Starter App writes to "output" topic

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm developing a custom starter app using the code [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tcp/tree/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-tcp), because I wanted to add `TcpSSLContextSupport` to it. I've managed to do that, and it worked fine on my local SCDF server, but now I want to deploy it on SCDF for Kubernetes over Google Cloud. I've created an [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/starkface/peppermint/) for it and it does work, but the behavior is a little unexpected.

I created a stream like: `stream create stream-name --definition "app-name | log"`.

First off, it created a topic as per convention `stream-name.app-name`, and I was expecting it to show me the messages there, but it actually writes into the "output" topic, which is strange. I haven't provided any additional configuration. I tried it with SCDF latest version as well as 1.2.0.RELEASE with the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the topic `stream-name.app-name` is created, the SCDF correctly sets the outbound destination name for your source app. Note that SCDF sets only the property `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination` for the apps. Here, the outbound channel is assumed to be `output`.

I guess you have a different binding target name for the `outbound` message channel in your custom application. Since SCDF doesn't set the destination for this app, the app defaults to `output` as the destination.

Check your `outbound` target name in your custom app. You need to set the property `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<customOutboundTargetName>.destination` as a deployment property for the app.

For instance,

```
dataflow:>stream deploy stream-name --properties "app.source-app-name.spring.cloud.stream.bindings.customOutboundTargetName.destination=yourTopic,app.sink-app-name.spring.cloud.stream.bindings.customInboudTargetName.destination=yourTopic"
```

Note: customOutboundTargetName and customInboundTargetName are set as `output` and `input` by default via SCDF.

Comment: I know about the configuration that I can add, but I'm trying to understand why Spring is doing this specifically with my custom app, but not when I use the `tcp | log` option, especially when I haven't changed anything that I can think of. And I also don't know what you mean when you said that Spring correctly sets the outbound channel when `stream-name.app-name` is created, because it clearly sets the outbound channel to `output` despite that?

Comment: All the out of the box apps come up with the outbound and inbound channel names as `output` and `input`. That's the reason SCDF sets the destination name using that channel name. If you use a different channel name in your custom app, then you need to configure as above.

Comment: Also, it is Spring Cloud Stream that sets the outbound destination name (topic) as `output` and it happens here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/config/BindingServiceProperties.java#L207

Comment: That makes sense. But why does it create the `stream-name.app-name` topic at all when it's going to write into the `output` topic?

Comment: I think that's because SCDF also assigns `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=stream-name.app-name`. I think SCDF can improvise this. Created https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/1519 to track it. Thanks!

Comment: So if `output` is the default, then why doesn't the log-sink consume from it? The log-sink consumes from the topic `stream-name.app-name`, which has nothing, as all the data is going into `output`.

Comment: Also, I should probably reiterate that with SCDF local and my app registered as a maven artifact, it works as expected by writing to the topic `stream-name.app-name`. But when I create a container and deploy it in SCDF for Kubernetes, the messages are written in `output`.

Comment: `output` is the default `destination` (topic) name where as SCDF sets the topic name as `stream-name.app-name`.  Since you have a custom named channel which isn't set with a specific destination name, the default `output` topic is created.